# Reason for ecg volume conduction waveform?

Tags: physiology, electrocardiogram

[image]

Can somebody for the love of humanity and genuine curiosity explain why does the voltage between 2 oppositely charged ends of a progressively depolarizing cell peak  when the wave reaches the middle of the cell as shown in the picture? And why does it begin to fall after that? I've tried to reason this out with everything that I know or had been taught about dipoles and charges and currents and whatnot, but I can't convince myself that I understand why this is happening. Please explain without using lines like "that's because that's where they are the most different"....coz such lines are the least helpful of all. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't look like a QRST pulse

Comment: Here's my 1st cut at a really unhealthy heart pulse. Waiting for short URL  https://tinyurl.com/2enl5amf  the force stores energy in L, C in a pulse then releases it.  Lower R dampens the wave.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

> that's because that's where they are the most different

is exactly right. You have two electrode sites, "blue" and "pink". [Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage) is an electrical potential *difference*.

If you sum up all the charges near "blue" and sum up all the charges near "pink" (where "near" means that closer charges matter more than those further away), in either your upper right or lower left plot, you'll get the same sum at blue and pink, so pink-blue = 0 = voltage.

If you sum up all the charges near "blue" in the top left plot, you'll get a negative number, if you sum up all the charges near "pink" in the top left plot you'll get a positive number.

When you "flip" a charge, it's going to affect both blue and pink, but it will affect the one it's closest to more. Therefore, if you were trying to design a scenario with the biggest difference, you'd want all the charges closest to blue to be opposite the charges closest to pink.

If you're somewhere in between the top two plots, say, take one of the positive charges to the right of the green arrow near pink and make it negative, you'll make both red and pink more negative. If the position of this charge were equally between the two electrodes, it would affect them both equally, and there'd be no difference in voltage. However, everything to the right of the green arrow is closer to pink, so any change there affects pink more than blue. That means that changing one of those positive charges to negative makes the positive pink electrode less positive by a larger amount than it makes the negative blue electrode more negative, so the difference is smaller.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a doubt here. Since the wave of depolarization (-ve charge) is progressing and growing in volume and therefore intensity, shouldn't the current keep on rising up instead of reducing after the midpoint? Coz as the -ve charge continues to build, it will push more current through the electrode?

Comment: @user25782 What "current" are you talking about?

Comment: Also what if we weren't comparing positive and negative charges but two points of overall positivity that are negative/positive relative to each other. E.g, point A is +12 and point B is +8. What then would we see? Thank you.

Comment: Well, why not plug it into the formula? Voltage is always a potential difference, so it's always B-A or A-B, depending on your conventions.

Comment: I was talking about the current flowing because of the development of oppositely charged poles in my previous to previous reply.

Comment: The plot here is just voltage, so just think of voltage. No need to worry about currents here.

Comment: But voltage is an abstract concept right? Its actually the current flowing through a voltmeter that causes it to deflect its needle?

Comment: Do you want to understand this plot, or understand how a voltmeter works? The plot is very simple - do not bring in extra stuff. Voltage as a concept may be somewhat abstract, but for understanding how electricity works or charges move, etc, it's very real.

Comment: I'm sorry for causing you annoyance, it's just that I'm horribly confused with this topic.

Comment: So if there are 2 points with overall positive charge but relatively negative/positive to each other and let's say when the wave is in the middle its +60 on 1 side and +50 on the other side. So +60-(+50) = 10. But when the wave shifts beyond that, suppose +70-(+40) = 30. So how in that case would voltage peak in the middle?

Comment: @user25782 What geometric circumstance are those numbers supposed to refer to?  Take the figure you posted and try to come up with one that has more charge separation between the blue and pink electrodes than the case in the upper left or lower right. Try switching a "-" to "+" or vice versa, and think about what the implications are at each electrode.

Comment: I know that the figure only shows a 50/50 scenario. I'm talking about the time when the wave will shift beyond the halfway point and there will be a brief imbalance, as one side will be more positive/negative than the other. My problem is how will it peak in the middle if the sum of charges at both ends is positive but one is less positive than the other like in the example I gave.

Comment: ....or is such a situation as proposed by me even possible??

Comment: @user25782 Draw it out and compare to the "50/50" case.

Comment: Don't know how to draw here. I wish I could explain my question better.

Comment: Check my edit, try to think of the consequence of changing one charge.

Comment: I understand that part of your edit, thank you for listening. But where my confusion lies is, say point A is at +90V membrane potential (just for the sake of this example) and point B is +20V membrane potential. How will then voltage peak in the middle? I'll be very grateful if you can simplify this for me like you did before.

Comment: All that matters is differences, the scenario you're describing doesn't make sense to me: +20V or +90V compared to *what*?

Comment: I mean at the respective points the potentials across the membrane are +90 and +20 . Now you have 2 points in the cell that are both positive overall yet one is "less positive" than the other. So how are we going to apply that 50/50 calculation here to prove that voltage would peak in in middle like you had in your first answer?

Comment: I don't know where your 20V and 90V are coming from, the scenario does not make sense. If through some magic you add 70V of voltage difference at all points in time then the peak will still be at the same place, you've just shifted the whole curve up (or down).